# How can I add assignees to a workflow more than once?

Tags: workflow, tasks, workflow-activity, task-assignment

I created an approval workflow in SharePoint designer. When this is started, it is assigned to several people, with someone twice (by design), such as A, B, C, and then A again. This works fine, and people in the workflow more than once get tasks assigned at the proper times. However, if someone tries to "Add or update assignees" on the Workflow Status screen, they are unable to add people MORE THAN ONCE. For example, they can't add person D, E, and then D again. Each additional assignee only seems to get one spot. Is there a way around this?

Also, on the "add or update assignees" screen, people that are in the workflow more than once are only shown once, so users know WHO is remaining, but if a person is in there more than once, they can't tell where each position is. Does anyone know if there is a way to see this?